# Why is my UIButton.tintColor not working?

Tags: ios, uibutton

My build target is set for IOS5 which is where I understand `UIButton.tintColor` was introduced...

I have this in my viewDidLoad for the View Controller

```
[timelineButton setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[timelineButton setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The text changes properly but the button isn't black?

Thanks!

Comment: According to the docs, "This property is not valid for all button types.". What button type are you using?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2):

> This property is not valid for all button types.

You need to switch your `buttonType` to another [one of these](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW39). (Unfortunately, the documentation does not specify which specific button types support this property.)

Comment: Just using a standard rounded rectangle type.  Doesn't work for that?

Comment: It does work for me in Storyboard / Interface Builder : set the button type to 'system', then set the background of the view (of the UIButton) to the desired color - works perfect!

Comment: Note for iOS 7: Using `UIButtonTypeSystem`, the button will automatically use `tintColor` for the title label's `textColor`.

Comment: Note for iOS 7: UIButtonTypeSystem trick works for textColor and imageColor

Comment: **Swift 3**

For anyone doing it programatically:

    `var button = UIButton(type: .system)`
   ` button.tintColor = UIColor.blue`

Answer (score 42):

Make sure your button "type" is set to System. If it is set to Custom it could be the reason the color of your button isn't changing. This is what happened to me and changing the type to System fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

It tint your highlighted State color.
When you tap/click on the UIButton the color specified with tintColor appears as long as you hold the tap/click on the UIButton.

```
resetButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.764 green:1.000 blue:0.000 alpha:1.000];
```

The button is white in normal state.
But if I tap on the button the color turns red, but only then.

**IF you need to change the button so it looks like a red or blue one in the UIControlStateNormal then**

Change the UIButtonType to UIButtonTypeCustom in Interface Builder or programmatically with

```
 UIButton *resetButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Change the attributes on your own and recreate the rounded corners

```
resetButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
resetButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
resetButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
resetButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
```

Comment: And don't forget to include  #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> for CALayer declarations.

Comment: Readers should be cautioned that this isn't enough -- as it is, the button does not react when you touch it.  You need to hook up some additional events to change the colors when pressed (see alexqinbj's answer below).

Answer (score 7):

As stated in other answers tint does not work for Custom Button types. Make sure you explicitly declare the button type. Do not just use [UIButton alloc] init]

This will work:

```
UIButton *mybutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[mybutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
mybutton.tintColor = [ODTheme blueTintColor];
```

Answer (score 5):

I found 3 things must be followed.

**1. Render image as `Default`**

Go to `Images.xcassets > Your Image > Show the Attributes inspector > Render As > Default`

[image: render as default]

**2. Make sure your button type is System**

**3. Now change button's tintColor.**

Done.

Answer (score 4):

Today, I also meet this problem. I use delegate to solve it.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressReset:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

-(void)buttonPress:(id)sender{
UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
NSLog(@"buttonPressed");
}

-(void)buttonPressReset:(id)sender{
UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
NSLog(@"buttonPressReset");
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite complete -- you should also add UIControlEventTouchDragEnter to the events that trigger buttonPress, and UIControlEventTouchDragExit to the events that trigger buttonPressReset.

Answer (score 3):

Should try this method:

```
- (void)setTitleColor:(UIColor *)color
             forState:(UIControlState)state
```

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 13 you can tint the image and then set it to the button:

```
let coloredImage = UIImage().withTintColor(UIColor.red)
UIButton().setImage(coloredImage, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply set your `UIButton` to type **System** in **Storyboard**.

[image]

And then in code just use:

```
myButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score 2):

If your UIButton type is system then and then only tint colour property is work. So first you need to set your button type to the system then apply tint colour for the specific state.

```
let btn = UIButton.init(type: .system)
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Now it will compile, but I don't think your answer is adding anything new to the other answers, you are just repeating what others said 5 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of the Button text you can use:

```
resetButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

Or OBJ-C:

```
- (void)setTitleColor:(UIColor *)color
         forState:(UIControlState)state
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitleColor:forState:

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:[yourButton.currentBackgroundImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[yourButton setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 :

```
yourButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really change the button type to `System` as I was inheriting from a closed internal library.

So, I changed the appearance API for UIButton

```
UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIButton.self]).tintColor =  .white
```