# Gimp Settings to Create a Tintable Icon in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, icons, gimp

I have a PNG file that's an arrow that I'd like to use as an icon in an iOS app. I've dropped other PNG files into Xcode and they work fine as tintable `UIButton` images using this line as an example:

```
[self.backButton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

With the PNG file I dropped in, the file I'm dropping in is transparent except for the arrow, which is black. The code above does nothing to the image I'm trying to tint.

I've found [other posts covering this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514066/how-to-tint-a-transparent-png-image-in-iphone), but rather than type 10-20 lines of code for each icon I've got on a `UIButton`, I'd rather save it with the correct settings in Gimp and just reference the file in Xcode.

What settings should I pay attention to when saving the file as a PNG in Gimp?

**Update**
I initially thought adding the tint was causing my app to crash, however a cache clean resolved that issue. Regardless, my `UIButton` with a PNG background won't change tints. It's always black, though it turns charcoal (darkGray?) colored if the button is disabled.

**Update 2**
I've tried this without any luck:

```
self.backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[self.backButton setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.backButton.tintColor = [UIColor myCustomColor];
```

Comment: Provide relevant code and details about the crash.

Comment: @rmaddy I updated my query. I cleaned the cache and the crash went away, but the issue w/ my PNG image on a button persists. It looks like every other PNG button image I open in Gimp, so I can only conclude I'm fouling up a setting when saving the PNG file

Comment: Under what method did you tint it?

Comment: 'viewDidLoad' is the method that code is contained in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and opted for a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`--works out better for the interface, so no compromise. Apparently, you can tint some buttons, but not others.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11066046/4475605