# How to keep tintColor in a UIButton then click on this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm, setting the tintColor to the UIImageView of a UIButton like this:

```
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
icon.image = [img imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
icon.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

This code is working, but then Click the UIButton, the color return to the initial color of UIImage.

How could I keep the green color added?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my UIButton.tintColor not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066008/why-is-my-uibutton-tintcolor-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this if help.

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@“imageName.png”] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        [_yourBtn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_yourBtn setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```